# How to give Rank in list of Object and sort on the basis of Rank and any other key?

Tags: java

I have a situation where I need to make a list of object , where Object have (Name, Title) element. for e.g. :

```
obj1 = ('john', 'colonel')
obj2 = ('Alex', 'major')
obj3 = ('Roy', 'Major general')
obj4 = ('derrick', 'no Rank')
```

I need to do sorting in two ways:
1. First on the Title basis.
2. For any two names, if the title is same then sorting of object on the 
   alphabetical name basis(like chronological order of name).
3. And also need to remove duplicate names from the list.

Please help me out as I know how to sort the arraylist but don't know how to give ranking and sort on multiple conditions. If you need further details or do not understand my question then please let me know.

Comment: consider using an enum

Comment: *How* do you want to sort on the title? Alphabetically?

Comment: Which do you want to remove in case of duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a `Comparator` Class, something like this:

```
class ObjectComparator implements Comparator<SomeClass>{

    @Override
    public int compare(SomeClass obj1, SomeClass obj2) {
        // if two objects' ranks are the same 
        if(obj1.rank.equals(obj2.rank)){
            // then compare their names
            return obj1.name.compareTo(obj2.name);
        }
        else{
            return obj1.rank.compareTo(obj2.rank);
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot understand how you want to remove the duplicates of the attribute `name` because that will ruin the *sorting*, unless you mean to remove the duplicates of the same `name` and `rank` (e.g. `obj1 = "john" "colonel"` and also `obj2 ="john" "colonel"`) then in this case straightforwardly use a `Set` after overriding the `equal` and `hashCode` methods in your class, so your set can know if the two objects are equal...something like this:

```
@Override
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other){
    if(other==null) return false;
    if (other == this) return true;
    return ((SomeClass)other).name.equalsIgnoreCase(this.name)
           && ((SomeClass)other).rank.equalsIgnoreCase(this.rank);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
   return Objects.hash(name, rank);
}
```

But if you mean that you want to remove the duplicates `name`s (i.e. objects have same fields but different ranks), then you may consider using a `LinkedHashMap` which preserves the order of items, but as I mentioned, this will *Not* preserve the sorting order for the particular duplicate (*TBH I don't think that what you meant by duplicates*)... an example for testing:

```
public class SomeClass{
    String name, rank;

    public SomeClass(String name, String rank){
        this.name = name;
        this.rank = rank;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeClass obj1 = new SomeClass("john", "colonel");
        SomeClass obj2 = new SomeClass("XXX", "major"); 
        SomeClass obj3 = new SomeClass("Roy", "general");
        SomeClass obj4 = new SomeClass("derrick", "no Rank");
        SomeClass obj5 = new SomeClass("john", "something");
        SomeClass obj6 = new SomeClass("Alex", "major");
        List<SomeClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(obj1); list.add(obj2); list.add(obj3);
        list.add(obj4); list.add(obj5); list.add(obj6);

        System.out.println(getSortedObjects(list));

    }

    public static Map<String, List<String>> getSortedObjects(List<SomeClass> list){
        Map<String, List<String>> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        // sort the list
        Collections.sort(list, new ObjectComparator());

        for(SomeClass obj : list){
            // for testing sorting before ruining it in a map 
            System.out.println(obj.name + " " + obj.rank);

            List<String> temp;
            if(sortedMap.containsKey(obj.name)){
               temp = sortedMap.get(obj.name);
               temp.add(obj.rank);
               sortedMap.put(obj.name, temp);
            }
            else{
                temp = new ArrayList<>();
                temp.add(obj.rank);
                sortedMap.put(obj.name, temp);
            }
        }

        return sortedMap;
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
john colonel
Roy general
Alex major
XXX major
derrick no Rank
john something
{john=[colonel, something], Roy=[general], Alex=[major], XXX=[major], derrick=[no Rank]}
```

---

**Complete Implementation Example of `Set` & `Comparator`:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

public class SomeClass{
    // suppose the fields in your class
    String name, rank;

    // simple constructor
    public SomeClass(String name, String rank){
        this.name = name;
        this.rank = rank;
    }


    // you need to override both equals and hashCode methods from
    // Object superclass in order the set works properly and realizes 
    // that two given objects of type SomeClass are equal
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other){
        if(other==null) return false;
        if (other == this) return true;
        return ((SomeClass)other).name.equalsIgnoreCase(this.name)
               && ((SomeClass)other).rank.equalsIgnoreCase(this.rank);
    }


    @Override
     public int hashCode() {
         return Objects.hash(name, rank);
     }


    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return name + " " + rank;
    }

    /**
     * Pass a set then add the items to a temporary ArrayList
     * to be sorted according to the Comparator condition
     * then clear the set and add the sorted element back
     * @param list
     */
    public static void sort(Set<SomeClass> list){
        List<SomeClass> temp = new ArrayList<>();
        temp.addAll(list);
        // anonymous class implementation of Comparator
        Collections.sort(temp, new Comparator<SomeClass>(){

                @Override
                public int compare(SomeClass obj1, SomeClass obj2) {
                    // if two objects' ranks are the same 
                    if(obj1.rank.equals(obj2.rank)){
                        // then compare their names
                        return obj1.name.compareTo(obj2.name);
                    }
                    else{
                        return obj1.rank.compareTo(obj2.rank);
                    }
                }});

        list.clear();
        list.addAll(temp);  
    }


    // testing
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create Objects of the class with duplicate
        SomeClass obj1 = new SomeClass("john", "colonel");
        SomeClass obj2 = new SomeClass("XXX", "major"); 
        SomeClass obj3 = new SomeClass("Roy", "general");
        SomeClass obj4 = new SomeClass("derrick", "no Rank");
        SomeClass obj5 = new SomeClass("john", "something");
        SomeClass obj6 = new SomeClass("Alex", "major");
        SomeClass obj7 = new SomeClass("Alex", "major"); // duplicate object


        // LinkedHashSet PRESERVES the order of elements' insertion
        // in addition to removing duplicates
        Set<SomeClass> list = new LinkedHashSet<>();

        // populate the set
        list.add(obj1); list.add(obj2); list.add(obj3);
        list.add(obj4); list.add(obj5); list.add(obj6);
        list.add(obj7);

        //before sorting
        System.out.println("Before " + list);

        // after sorting
        sort(list);
        System.out.println("After " + list);

    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
Before [john colonel, XXX major, Roy general, derrick no Rank, john something, Alex major]
After  [john colonel, Roy general, Alex major, XXX major, derrick no Rank, john something]
```

Comment: Thanks Yaha and Ryan, for your comments. It solves my problem.

Comment: Thanks yaha for your valuable efforts, Yes, I confirm that I will not get duplicates records and no need to remove duplicates. One more thing I need to add which I done after getting information about compare method is that after sorting I was still not getting the correct alphabetical order of name for same Rank. I was actually implementing two level of sorting first on the basis of Rank then if same title for two name then name should appear in alphabetical order without disturbing the order of Rank. You give me correct pointer and I implement it. I will share my code once I get the access.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read up on Comparators, and implement one for your class.

If you are using Java 8, the easiest way is to use Comparators.comparing

https://praveer09.github.io/technology/2016/06/21/writing-comparators-the-java8-way/

In order to prevent duplicate names, I would keep a separate Set (which automatically constrains uniqueness) of names that already exist. Check to see if that set contains the names before you add the new object to the arraylist.